# Crypt cannot be resolved

Tags: java, java-7

I am working in Java security.

I imported following  package.

```
import java.security.*;
```

and I am using crypt as `Crypt.createSha(fPrint);`

while compiling it saying `Crypt` cannot be resolved.

any suggestions.

Comment: What makes you think there's a `Crypt` class in `java.security`?

Comment: That class does not exist in the [`java.security`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/package-summary.html) package.

Comment: You need to include the external lib,this class not exist in this package

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q="Crypt.createSha" => nothing, that's a bad sign

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Crypt`  is not a class in  `java.security` package. If you want to create a sha1 hashing,
Use the `MessageDigest` class and supply data piece by piece. The example below ignores details like turning byte[] into string and closing the file, but should give you the general idea.

```
public byte[] createSha1(File file) throws Exception  {
    MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
    InputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    int n = 0;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
    while (n != -1) {
        n = fis.read(buffer);
        if (n > 0) {
            digest.update(buffer, 0, n);
        }
    }
    return digest.digest();
}
```

Comment: please close your stream

Comment: please read the answer carefully. I already said i am only giving you a general idea, not complete code.